# What does "ring of truth" refer to?

Tags: american-english

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, After Gretchen filed a sexual lawsuit against Roger,
Host Jeannine called Anchor Greta to tell about what Jeannie
talked to "The Warp" online publication :

> Jeannine: I said, "I don't think Gretchen Carlson has a friend in the
> building."
>
> Greta: I know, Roger. Someone would've told me.
>
> Jeannine: They're gonna quote me on that.
>
> Greta: Not a **ring of truth**.

What does "ring of truth" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ring+true) says,

***ring** meaning "resonance of coin or glass as a test of genuineness" is from 1850, with transferred use (ring of truth, etc.).*'

So Greta is saying it doesn't sound true, though I can't tell what she's referring to. And I don't know why she calls Jeannine "Roger", but maybe it's your punctuation.

(I don't think this expression is *American* English, btw.)

Comment: Roger means Roger Ailes not Jeannie.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be a comma in "I know, Roger".

Comment: @NomadHill - Who's Jeannie?

Comment: This is a very old cliché in English. Used in AmE, too.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from "*having a/the ring of truth*":

> to seem to be true
> <sup>[source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-the-ring-of-truth)</sup>

While it's not clear to me from the context you provide, Greta either implies Jeannine's remark doesn't come across as truthful, or suggests Jeannine ought not to spill the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Ring of truth

Means: **sounds like the truth.**

Ring is like a bell or telephone. Not like what you put on your finger.

Often, one also sees: That rings true or That doesn't ring true.